# FFMPEG install on server

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp3, converters, shared

I have an online server (shared hosting plan) in linux, i do not know a lot stuff about linux and i am trying to install ffmpeg.

I have tryied a lot of scripts but no luck.
Now i am trying to install the below script via putty.
`https://github.com/heidisoft/FFMPEG-install-script-for-shared-host`

When the install was running i get this message and the installation stops...

```
Installation of MPlayer-1.0rc1.tar.bz2 ....... started
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1233  100  1233    0     0   7713      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7803
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
mplayer.sh: line 32: cd: MPlayer-1.0rc1/: No such file or directory
mplayer.sh: line 33: ./configure: No such file or directory
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
cp: cannot stat `etc/codecs.conf': No such file or directory
Installation of MPlayer-1.0rc1.tar.bz2 ....... Completed

        Mplayer installation Failed :( , please visit the forum
```

What can i do to install??? Thanks!

Comment: This script should not be used. It apparently installs ffmpeg SVN r10820 which is incredibly outdated and not supported. A simpler solution would be to use a [Linux build of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is failing because you are not downloading the MPlayer source archive but rather an error web page. This makes extracting the archive fail which makes changing directories and compiling fail.

To try and get ffmpeg installed

1. Double check to see if you have or can get privileges to install binary packages.
2. Try and get technical support to install the packages you need.
3. Try to follow the scripts manually substituting in updated versions of the software.
4. I think the release you are trying to install is 7 years old. Installing it on a server is almost certainly a bad idea. However if you feel your only choice is to use this script compile from source. You can find a mirror site that hosts the version of MPlayer you are trying to install and edit mplayer.sh to use that URL. I do not remember mplayer being a dependency for ffmpeg so you might be able to skip this step by commenting out the mplayer install section from start.sh and continue on to installing ffmpeg.

Some notes:
Your hosting service might object to using the server for any kind of CPU intensive process like transcoding video.
If the Internet at large can access the obsolete programs you are trying to install you may be hacked.

Comment: Thanks guys, but i see that my host does not allowed the installation of ffmpeg as is shared hosting account, i have tried a lot of scripts and i found yesterday that my host have it, in perl plugins, so i tried to install it via cpanel and again nothing!